# Ayuda con error en juego de Ping Pong

Tags: javascript

En este momento me encuentro programando un juego de Ping Pong y me estoy apoyando en un tutorial para hacerlo. La cuestion es que tengo un error del tipo:

> ```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
> ```

y no encuentro solución alguna

```
const callback  (millis) => {
        if (lastTime) {
            this.update( (millis - lastTime) / 1000 );
        }
        lastTime = millis;
        requestAnimationFrame(callback);
    };
```

Comment: Missing initializer in const declaration = Falta inicialización en la declaración de la constante. Agrega un poco más de contexto a tu pregunta. Usa esta guía [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Si te fijas el error dice que no se encuentra un inicializador para la constante callback  por que te falta el signo de igual. Trata con esto.

```
const callback = (millis) => {
    if (lastTime) {
        this.update( (millis - lastTime) / 1000 );
    }
    lastTime = millis;
    requestAnimationFrame(callback);
};
```